# The authoritative way to pass values from PHP to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I guess I am looking for a best method of passing values: arrays, objects, JSON -- any data -- from PHP to javascript.

So far I've just seen:

```
   PHP - json_encode(value); 
   Javascript - eval()
```

and a variation of that by using json2.js or the alike.

Comment: yep... you pretty much got it...  although I'd recommend the json2.js method.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has:

- [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) --> decode
- [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) --> encode

JavaScript ([json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)) has:

- `JSON.stringify` --> encode
- `JSON.parse`     --> decode

Comment: jerone's got it. Don't use eval() in javascript for the data you are parsing, its a security problem: http://json.org/js.html